# Why is my looping scrollview jumping around?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a horizontal scrollview that loops. All the solutions I've found online for this problem include adding copies of items at the beginning or end of the list. The element(s) inside have state and their appearance changes based on that state.

The problem is that when reaching the end, the next (first) item is stuck with its initial state rather than the current state. This results in jerky behavior: [screen recording](https://youtu.be/ysSo8XF-hZk)

I've tried this with every example I've found online with very similar results each time. The example in the video is made with the following code, although you can find the working bare-bones example here: [Github](https://github.com/Cecile-Lebleu/LoopScroll)

```swift
struct InfiniteHorizontalScrollView2<Content: View, Item: RandomAccessCollection>: View where Item.Element: Identifiable {
    var width: CGFloat
    var items: Item
    var repeatingCount = 1
    @ViewBuilder var content: (Item.Element) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    content(item)
                }
                
                ForEach(0..<repeatingCount, id: \.self) { index in
                    let item = Array(items)[index % items.count]
                    content(item)
                }
            }
            .background {
                ScrollViewHelper(
                    width: width,
                    itemsCount: items.count
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollViewHelper: UIViewRepresentable {
    var width: CGFloat
    var itemsCount: Int
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(
            width: width,
            itemsCount: itemsCount
        )
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        return .init()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.06) {
            if let scrollView = uiView.superview?.superview?.superview as? UIScrollView, !context.coordinator.isAdded {
                scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
                context.coordinator.isAdded = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var width: CGFloat
        var itemsCount: Int
        
        init(
            width: CGFloat,
            itemsCount: Int
        ) {
            self.width = width
            self.itemsCount = itemsCount
        }
        
        var isAdded: Bool = false
        
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let minX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
            let mainContentSize = CGFloat(itemsCount) * width
            
            if minX > mainContentSize {
                scrollView.contentOffset.x -= mainContentSize
            }
            
            if minX < 0 {
                scrollView.contentOffset.x += mainContentSize
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The sample doesn't compile. There were some files in the repo not added to the project, but even after adding those, *Value of Content has no member float*

Comment: Does [this](https://www.appcoda.com/scrollview-paging/) help?

Comment: I think your problem is that there is no binding between `Item` and `Block` - So when you update `active` in the `Block` view Swift UI doesn't know that the view needs to be refreshed. `Item` is your model, but you aren't updating it. You are only updating the state in a view.

Comment: @Paulw11 that fixed it! I've updated the repo. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. If you'd like to answer the question, I'll mark it as accepted.